# Good fallback for localStorage, sessionStorage and then cookie?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I'm trying to figure out the best fallback method for storing data when someone visits our site. We use this to store search filter preferences in particular, that need to move across the site as they move around. Ideally it would work with:

- localStorage first
- fallback to sessionStorage
- then fallback to cookies

My current setup looks a bit like:

```
var localStorageAvail = supports_html5_storage();
var storage = "local";
if (localStorageAvail == undefined || localStorageAvail == false || localStorageAvail == null) {
    storage = "cookie";
}

function supports_html5_storage() {
  var testKey = 'test', storage = window.localStorage;
  try {
    storage.setItem(testKey, '1');
    storage.removeItem(testKey);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

function getValue(what) {
    if (storage == "cookie") {
        // get from cookie
        return readCookie(what);
    } else {
        // localstorage
        return localStorage.getItem(what)
    }
}

function setValue(what,value) {
    if (storage == "cookie") {
        // get from cookie
        writeCookie(what,value,365);
    } else {
        // localstorage
        localStorage.setItem(what,value)
    }
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


function writeCookie(name,value,days) {
   var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

**FWIW**, I'm not using jQuery, and I don't want to have to include extra libraries to do this. It needs to all be in Vanilla JS :)

**My question:** What is the best way to do this? Should I just tweak my current method, so it includes `sessionStorage` as well? Or are there better methods to do this?

Comment: You didn't ask a question

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry I thought it was self explanatory. I've added my question to the OP now.

Comment: The "best" way in my opinion is to use a library that handles it for you.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 mmm I was trying to avoid that :) Do you have any in particular? I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but a the same time a lot of these libs are bloated with stuff I don't need

Comment: @AndrewNewby [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) is a popular one. It can automatically pick the best one for you and falls back to the one that works next, or you can cherry-pick which ones you want to use. Or [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) for larger async storages.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks, that does look interesting :) I'll have a play with it, as it looks like it will do the job nicely (and only 7kb, so thats pretty decent too!). If you could add this as an answer, I will accept :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby It's okay, even if I put it as an answer it would get marked for deletion as a "link only answer" anyway ;)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 haha fair enough. Thanks for your help though :) I've been trawling over pages / code samples / blogs / SO posts for a good couple of hours now, and there just wasn't a general agreement on anything!